# MVVM Binding not working in design-time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I tried to bind the visibility of a few buttons to some booleans in a viewmodel and make it work in design-time. I did this several times and never had a problem, but now it does not work and I don't have a clue why. Note that everything works 
fine when I run the application.

I extracted the essence into a separate app and it still doesn't work!

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:bindingTest="clr-namespace:BindingTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance bindingTest:TestViewModel, d:IsDesignTimeCreatable=true}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Visibility="{Binding IsButton1Visible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">Hallo 1</Button>
            <Button Visibility="{Binding Button2Visibility}">Hallo 2</Button>
            <Button>Hallo 3</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public bool IsButton1Visible
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public Visibility Button2Visibility
    {
        get { return Visibility.Hidden; }
    }
}
```

To make it work in the real app, i added to the constructor of the XAML:

```
DataContext = new TestViewModel();
```

This is all pretty simple, but why is it not working in the designer?? I always got this to work in the past and now I tried for hours... It's not the only binding not working, but why is not even this working??

Expected Result:

- Button1 visible
- Button2 hidden
- Button3 visible

Result in the designer:

- Button1 collapsed
- Button2 visible
- Button3 visible

Comment: Your ViewModel does not expose Boolean but Visibility type.

Comment: @E-Bat, look again...

Comment: I just added the Visibility to test if at least _something_ would work. But even the Visibility binding does not work as expected...

Comment: @JCH2k, i just tested with VS2015 community edition, and i could not observe the problems. The designtime DataContext works just fine. Hmm, try cleaning your solution, restart VS, and rebuild it again. Also, try disabling any extensions you might using...

Comment: Wait... Do not use the namespace `BindingTest`

Comment: I did the test originally with the namespace `WpfApplication1`, but i thought that Microsoft would be perhaps a bit silly, and i changed the namespace according to your example. Now all three buttons show up... wtf?

Comment: Does changing the namespace work for you, too?

Comment: @elgonzo thanks for clarify, I used the same code as in the Q and worked fine in my box.

Comment: Okay, i think i was shooting too quickly there with my assumption with regard to namespaces. The behaviour seems to be erratic, sometimes the design data works after a (re)build, sometimes not. I could not pinpoint it -- it does not seem to matter whether i have the XAML already open in VS or whether i restart VS... this is nasty...

Comment: I copied it (again) into a clean solution, but still it never works. I'm using VS 2013 Pro. In Blend it's not working either...

Comment: Just keep the XAML open in VS, and rebuild the test project a few times. On my box, different buttons (including the third one) appear or disappear after rebuilds. This is truly bizarre... VS2015 bug? (I have no older VS like VS2013 here to test against.)

Comment: @JCH2k, make sure in the constructor of the view you are checking if you are running in design mode or not.            if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            {
                DataContext = new TestViewModel();
            }

Comment: FYI: I have not set the real DataContext (neither programmatically nor in XAML), only the designtime DataContext.

Comment: I am going to check now whether the bizarre behavior has something to do with binding against the visibility property, or it also happens when i bind against other button properties...

Comment: I have bound the Content properties of the first two buttons with a string property and an int property. I also removed the visibility bindings. Now after each rebuild, the first button (bound to a string property) shows always "Content1" -- which is the name of the property, not its value (yes, i double-checked, the binding is correct). The content of the second button are random numbers (always positive two digit integers for me), but not the int value of the property it is bound too. Whoa...

Comment: OMG! All my bindings in MY WHOLE APPLICATION aren't working any more in the designer!!! I even rebooted my machine!

Comment: I did a quick googling, but could not find something with regard to this issue (i will google some more later, though). I did WPF until a year ago or so with VS2013, also using designtime DataContexts (which were far more complex than that simplistic test we do here) and i never encountered any problems. I don't know, but i would not be surprised if some VS2013 update broke that feature for you, and MS kindly also incorporated the bug into VS2015...

Comment: FYI: I just sent a "frown" (MS "baby speak" for issue report) to MS. Let's see what happens...

Comment: I downloaded the Community version of VS2015 and i can reproduce exactly the same weird behaviour when recompiling. Buttons come and go, some bindings work, some not. Bindings in my "big app" don't work in VS2015 either :-( Thanks for filing the report!

Comment: Okay, i seem to have found the problem. Brace yourself, this is rather ridiculous: remove the namespace prefix `d:` from the attribute `IsDesignTimeCreatable` and it should work (it does for me... i will update my answer shortly...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The problem with design-time DataContext bindings not working is due to mistakenly using the `d:` namespace prefix for the *IsDesignTimeCreatable* property.

So, change

```
d:IsDesignTimeCreatable=True
```

to

```
IsDesignTimeCreatable=True
```

and everything should be fine. (My bug report filed with MS will be updated with this information as well.)

---

As this problem with the design-time DataContext bindings not working was consistently reproducable in VS2015 as well as VS2013 when *IsDesignTimeCreatable* is prefixed with the `d:` namespace (see comments below the question), i decided to file a bug report with Microsoft: [Issue #1651633 "WPF designer: Designtime DataContext bindings broken?"](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1651633).

Lets see how Microsofts will follow-up with regard to this issue. It should be addressed, since such an issue can catch a developer off-guard and make him reinstall Visual Studio for no benefit... ;)

Comment: Can't believe it! This is ridiculous indeed! Why is there an _IsDesignTimeCreatable_ in both namespaces?? Many many thanks for your efforts!!

Comment: @JCH2k, there is a need for *d:IsDesignTimeCreatable* in certain situations -- [see here for an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/unnir/archive/2009/07/12/introducing-sample-data-for-developers.aspx) using a typed data template. What i would expect is the XAML parser not just swallowing *d:IsDesignTimeCreatable* for the *DesignInstance* while silently only taking the default value of *IsDesignTimeCreatable* (false) into account. Rather, with regard to *DesignInstance* i would like the parser to either enforce proper usage of *IsDesignTimeCreatable* or handle the property with or without `d:`.

Answer (score 3):

If anything is OK with the code, there could be an other tricky problem:

In the **Designer** of Visual Studio a **new button** was introduced in 2019, which **enables / disables the preview of design data**.

It's a very tiny button on botton left of the designer window. It's tooltip is "Enable Project Code".

Click this important toggle button to see the design data. (But be aware that you don't disable it, if it's already enabled.)

[image: Button to enable designer data]